# Javascript ler arquivo txt e interpretar como código

Tags: javascript, html

Estou trabalhando com o seguinte código para importar e mostrar arquivos de texto:

HTML

```
<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'>
<div id='output'>...</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var openFile = function (event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var text = reader.result;
        var node = document.getElementById('output');
        node.innerText = text;
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

Mas me surgiu a necessidade de que ao importar, o conteúdo seja interpretado como HTML, pois o arquivo contém listas em `<ul><li>`.

Isso seria possível? Se sim, podem me explicar o que devo alterar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `.innerText` irá inserir o conteúdo em forma de texto puro, ou seja, códigos HTML serão tratados como texto.

O `.innerHTML` irá inserir tanto texto como renderizar códigos HTML se houver.

Basta trocar `node.innerText = text;` por `node.innerHTML = text;`.